# Entity Framework count slow with TAKE(number)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

In my table there are 4000 rows.

When I use `context.table.Count()`, the result is returned in less than 1 minute, but when I use `context.table.Take(500).Count()`, I get a timeout.

I use `Take(500)` because the table will be larger than 6000000 rows.

Comment: When you say `context.table.Count()` it get's translated to something similar to `SELECT Count(*) FROM table`, which probably is just a lookup of a statistic entry and only one single integer is pushed over the wire from the SQL server to your application. When you do `context.table.Take(500).Count()`, it get's translated to something similar to `SELECT * FROM table`, then all that data is pushed over the wire, then all the entities are filled and finally they are counted. That's a lot more work and _a lot_ more data being moved around.

Comment: Take(500) return you 500 records so I could not understand ``count`` with ``take``.

Comment: What is the **structure** of that table? And also: do you have any indices on that table?

Comment: @Corak no, Take(n).Count() does not involve transmitting the records and dehydrating the entities. It does get compiled into a helluva lot more complex SQL than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` though. @OP, you probably simplified this? Is there a WHERE, are there related entities? What does the generated SQL look like, and what does your execution plan say about it?

Comment: Also, using `.Take(500)` without an `.OrderBy()` is kinda useless - which 500 rows do you expect to get? It's undefined - you'll get 500 arbitrary rows.

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya: well - you're *asking* for 500 rows - but there's no guarantee you'll really *get* 500 rows - maybe there's only 375 rows left ......

Comment: Check these suggestions https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/how-to-make-select-count-queries-crazy-fast/

Comment: if I have (10000000000) rows when I do **`.Count()`** it will take a lot of time but I just need to get count of item if **`.Where(e=>)`** result have low than 500 and If result more I don't want to take long time to get count of them